# make videojs seekbar vertical

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, video.js

I'm working on a project and in that project, I need to change the seek bar of html5 player to vertical along the video height. I tried a lot but couldn't find any solution. Then I used `videojs` as my HTML5 player, and now what I'm doing is rotating div of it's seek bar to `90 degrees` and then adjusting left and top properties to adjust its position with video. I know this is not very good approach to do this but I couldn't find any solution so I used this approach for now. But a second problem is happening and it's that I cannot seek video by clicking on the `seekbar`, it just starts the video from zero if I click the `seekbar`, If I don't rotate and dont' set positions with left, top properties, then seek is working fine. After trying many hours on internet, I'm lost, so I came here looking for solutions, is there any possible way to have my seekbar vertical with video height and also enable seeking? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Try to find out how the `seekbar` is registering mouse clicks, it should be somewhere in the Video.js library.

Comment: I tried it, the event is firing but as the orientation of `seekbar` is changed, that's why it's not firing trigger properly. I tried but no solution yet, so I left that project :-(

Answer (score 0):

In the `getPointerPosition` you need to change `position.y = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, (pageY - boxY) / boxW))`. You also need to find `var sizeKey` and change it to `var sizeKey = _this2.vertical() ? 'width' : 'width'`;